# date localization in iphone

Tags: iphone, localization, nsdate

I need to localize the  date. i tried with following code but its giving wrong thing.

For Example if my locale is "US" if i take date like(06 August 2011, 10:55 A.M.) from date picker and store in database then after i changed to locale to "Dutch" its working fine, it converts into dutch like (06 augustus 2011 10:55)

If i take date from date picker like (06 augustus 2011 10:55) for locale "Dutch" then I am changing to locale to "US" its display like(06 July 2011 10:55 A.M.),but it should be like(06 August 2011 10:55 A.M.).

I use below code for get date local date from string:

```
NSDate *past = [NSDate dateWithNaturalLanguageString:@"06 augustus 2011 10:55" locale:  [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dictionaryRepresentation]];
```

please help out me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going about this the wrong way. You should not store localized strings in your database, just store the actual -date returned from UIDatePicker.

Use NSDate all the time, and only when you display to the user do you use a NSDateFormatter to show the date in the user's appropriate locale.

Hope this helps!